# Guitar Hero Type Metronome

Tags: iphone, objective-c, algorithm, sdk

I'm trying to create a guitar hero type game and I'm working on a horizontal metronome where a dot crosses a certain vertical line means to play a note.

The metronome starts when the note is 5 seconds from being played then moves across and finally hits the vertical line. Are there any algorithms for making the dot move at the correct speed so it hits the line in exactly 5 seconds.

Also the image movement is very choppy. Is there any way to smooth the movement of the image across the view?

I would appreciate any feedback, thanks.

Comment: A metronome keeps time for music. A metrognome is an earth spirit that lives in the central city. I presume you mean the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

High-school physics - `velocity = distance / time`

Also, you probably don't really want "5 seconds" as your fixed preparation time for every song. 1 or 2 bars (at the song's tempo) would be better.